# C: print longest string in a dynamic allocated array of chars

Tags: arrays, c

I've made a dynamic allocated array of chars and read some lines of text from a .txt file. How can I find the longest "string" in the array?

The .txt file looks like this:

```
usr
user
username
somerandomtext
```

Here's my code that loads the array and prints it:

```
char c = fgetc(rezultati);
printf("\n");
int x = 0;
while (c != EOF){
     pogg[x++] = c;
     c = fgetc(rezultati);
}
pogg[x] = '\0';
printf("%s\n\n", pogg);
```

I have tried using qsort with a custom comparator function buy my output is just lines of ^2 (squared).

Comment: Read each line with `fgets()`. Use `strlen()` to get the length of the line, and compare this with the longest line read so far.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line using `fgets()`, and get the length of the line. Save the longest line in another variable.

You don't need an array of all the lines for this.

```
#define MAXLEN 200

char buffer[MAXLEN], longest[MAXLEN] = "";
size_t maxlength = 0;

while(fgets(buffer, MAXLEN, stdin) {
    if (strlen(buffer) > maxlength) {
        strcpy(longest, buffer);
    }
}
printf("Longest line = %s\n", longest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the function "strlen" You will then store the lengths in an array and compare them.

```
maxlen = arrayOfLengths[0];
while (i !=0) {

len = strlen(arrayOflengths[i]);
if (len > maxlen) {
    maxlen = len;
    maxindex = i;}
```

This has been little bit pseudocode-ish but still, I think that it will give you some idea.